# Cant install wine (from PPA) it gives me the following error

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 or
                 wine1.8 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy wine wine1.6 wine1.8` to your question and use code formatting (**`{}`**-button in the question editor).

Comment: Like this?i cant post the results because i dont have 10 reputation points but the results that i had when inserting the command is that no software as installed regarding to wine

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

Comment: it gave me the same error 
wine1.6 : Depende: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Não foi possível corrigir problemas, você tem pacotes mantidos (hold) estragados. i have this in portuguese sorry if it gets complicated not having in english because i dont know how to change the terminal language only

Comment: You get English outputs by writing `LANG=C` before a command, like `LANG=C apt-cache policy wine wine1.6 wine1.8`. And you can post the output if you use code formatting. Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to learn how to format your question.

Comment: i cant post the output it says its too long but what i can tell from it its that nothing was installed and that the problem still presists